# Change background color with color gradients

Tags: wpf, colors, background-color, gradient

I want to change the background color from my combobox.
But I would like to retain the color gradients.

[image]

I've tried using this code but still does not get the effect.

```
<Setter Property="Background" Value="White"/> <!-- It's only white :( -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<ComboBox>
    <ComboBox.Background>
        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1">
            <GradientStopCollection>
                <GradientStop Color="Blue" Offset="0.5" />
                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.5" />
            </GradientStopCollection>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </ComboBox.Background>
</ComboBox>
```

This will change the background color. Change the Color and Offset to get your desired result.